# Sync folder of VMWare host and guest

Tags: synchronization, vmware-workstation, remote-backup

I am running Win 7 for everyday use, but for development I power up VMWare Workstation 9 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed. What is the easiest way to keep my sourcecode developed in the guest system in sync with the host? (e.g. for the case of guest system failure - I always consider these as disposable.)

Approaches I could think of:

- Some kind of "folder sharing" as known from windows-only networks
- Using some VM feature to mount a host folder into the guest
- having an SVN server on the host (Tortoise) reachable from withhin the guest
- Using some Unix feature to upload files via Net to the host

What is the most common / best practise way? One goal it to keep the host system clean and with a minimum of additional software, while I don´t mind what to install on the guest. I would prefer some VMware approach, I exists. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest VMware approach would be to utilize shared folders. You can reference [this](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html) link for more information regarding shared folders and [this](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html) link details how to mount shared folders on Linux guests